# I want to add a receptacle to a circuit with a traveler

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I'm adding a receptacle on the exterior wall and I'd like to power it from a very conveniently located gang box which on the interior side of the wall.  The existing box is covered with a blank plate, and since it is 5 1/2 feet off the floor, it must have been for a wall sconce.  Inside the box are three pieces of Romex:  two are three wire, but the third has a red traveler.  Everything is connected with wire nuts:  NUT 1 - all white.  NUT 2 - black from one romex, and red from the 4 wire.  NUT 3 - black from the last piece of romex, black from the 4 wire, and then a black wire that connects NUTS 2 and 3.

It seems to me that I can add my new romex to NUT 1 and NUT 3, and I should be ok.  I highly doubt this is to code, so I anticipate that any advice will come with the caveat that this isn't to code.   I'm in New Jersey, and thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch box(es) that control power to this junction?  It'd also help if you pulled the nuts out more and got us a square-on shot of the inside of the box you're tapping from...

Comment: Looks like a former traveler / 3-way  that was retired.  Essentially *all* the hots in the entire box are nutted together.  The jumper is superflouous but may reveal previous intent, perhaps the red was once switched-hot while the black was once always-hot (i.e. not necessarily travelers).

Comment: Thanks, I agree 100%.  I switched off the circuit at the box, and the everything went dead as expected (no 2nd circuit on the traveler).  So I connected ground to ground, white to white, black to black, and all worked out.  After working on it, I think this must have been a switch leg to an outdoor light that was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if this is on a traveler circuit

- Do you have two switches somewhere that controls that circuit ?

I think your logic about what you intend to do is fine. You will have a hot a neutral and a ground.

One of the things that looks off to me is that normally your switches have the traveler between them and not your luminary box. You would see here Two 4 wire romex's [red to red ]and then your 3 way power romex - perhaps you had two sconce lamp receptacles..